# Trying to insert rows with smartsheet-api and php

Tags: smartsheet-api

I am able to update a row easily, but for the life of me can't get a new row inserted.
Here's my data:

```
{
    "toTop":true,
    "cells": [
        {
            "columnId": 5830169266022276,
            "value": true
        },
        {
            "columnId": 5830169266022276,
            "value": "New status",
            "strict": false
        }
    ]
},
{
    "toTop":true,
    "cells": [
        {
            "columnId": 5830169266022276,
            "value": true
        },
        {
            "columnId": 5830169266022276,
            "value": "New status",
            "strict": false
        }
    ]
}
```

The error I get is:

```
Required object attribute(s) are missing from your request: id.
```

Help, please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on that error message, I'd suspect that perhaps you're trying to use the verb `PUT` on your "Add Row" request. (If you're sending `PUT`, then Smartsheet thinks you want to update a row and therefore requires that you specify the **id** of the row.) The command to Add a Row should use the verb `POST`:

`POST /sheets/(sheetId}/rows`

Also, I notice that you're specifying the same cell (i.e., `columnId`) twice for each row. This might be problematic as well. Each row object should contain cell objects corresponding to columns that you want to update in that row -- and `columnId` value should not be repeated/duplicated within a given row.

Comment: I happened to figure that out right before I saw your answer. You are exactly right--thank you so much for taking the time to respond!